# How to maintain the position of Bootstrap carousel indicators in a carousel with only text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have implemented a bootstrap carousel only with text to put some quotes. 
When the text occupies two lines, the indicators move down to maintain the same distance with the text. Is it possible to prevent this? I've tried modifying the css of .carousel-indicators with no success. I would prefer to have the indicators always in the same place, although it implies to have them a little bit further in the captions with only one line of text.

The only css applied now to carousel-indicators:

```
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `bottom` works for positioned elements. [Check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom). Add `position: absolute` or give a height to the text block if all quotes take same height

Comment: Thank you @anpsmn! I had applied the height class to the #carousel instead of to the tag that is actually containing the text... Thanks again! :)